# Programmatically assigned eventhandler not showing up in HTML onClick attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently having a problem with event handlers assigned in the code-behind not appearing in the HTML code of the .aspx page. Below is the code fragment that does that:

```
HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

foreach(XmlNode item in IDList)
{
    LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
    btn.Text = item.InnerText;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
    cell.Controls.add(btn);
    row.cells.add(cell);
}

table.rows.add(row);
```

Something like that, more or less. So when I run the page and inspected the buttons using FireBug, I noticed that the eventhandler names for the buttons created have been changed to the LinkButtons' unique ID(ct125, 126, 127, etc), I think, and not "btn_Click"

I'm hoping to hear if anyone else has faced this problem before and found a solution for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your buttons might be using submit behavior for your buttons. Try setting "UseSubmitBehavior=false" for the buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this code to work as expected.  I dynamically add 4 `LinkButton`s and wire the Click event to a function `btn_Click`.  When I click each link, they call the `btn_Click` method server-side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

    for (int loop = 1; loop < 5; loop++)
    {
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.Text = "Test " + loop.ToString();
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);

    // Add the table to a placeholder.
    phInputs.Controls.Add(table);
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something to catch a breakpoint.
    var x = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating controls dynamically, you should assign them Id also, otherwise asp.net will auto-assign them ids like ctl{somenumber}. Also, you need to recreate these controls on each postback, otherwise your eventhandlers will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it fixed, but I'm absolutely bewildered at why it got fixed this way.

```
{
    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    int btnIndex = 0;

    foreach(XmlNode item in IDList)
    {
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.Text = item.InnerText;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btn.ID = "Btn_Page" + btnIndex.ToString();

        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        cell.Controls.add(btn);
        row.cells.add(cell);
    }

    table.rows.add(row);
}

protected void Btn_Page_0(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    whatever eventhandler code
}
```

When I inspected the HTML again, the names of the event handler assigned to the buttons are still being changed to its ID.

```
<a id="Btn_Page_0" href="javascript:_doPostback('Btn_Page_0','')">
```

So for each of those buttons, their event handlers are changed to `Btn_Page_0`, `Btn_Page_1`, `Btn_Page_2`, etc.

Strange thing is, they all go back to the `Btn_Page_0` event handler when clicked, instead of `btn_click`

So.....yeah. Kinda boggles my mind why it worked like this, but it works anyhow...